# Pyvmomi : Capture vcenter reset event for vms

Tags: reset, vcenter, pyvmomi

I am using pyvmomi for capturing vcenter events using WaitForUpdatesEx method.
But it is not able to capture vm's reset event as there is no property change in this case.

It is capturing poweron, poweroff, suspend events as state changes for them.
For all other vm related events, i am in constant state of waiting using WaitForUpdatesEx method.

Can anyone help me as i have a case where i want to perform some specific action in case vm reset event has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

There are no events for that. If you look at the documentation for that method it has no events: http://www.yavijava.com/docs/vim.VirtualMachine.html#reset

What you could try is a task history collector and respond when that task completes successfully.